# How to add environment variables to dart run?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add environment variables to `dart run` to start a VM console app?

I didn't find any explanation in the Dart documentation.

https://dart.dev/tools/dart-run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ dart --version`

```
Dart SDK version: 2.17.1 (stable) (Tue May 17 17:58:21 2022 +0000) on "macos_arm64"
```

`$ dart run --help`

```
Run a Dart program.

Usage: dart run [arguments] [<dart-file|package-target> [args]]

-D, --define=<key=value>                               Define an environment declaration.
```

There are two "environments" available to Dart.

1. The OS process environment available through `Platform.environment`. I
   believe it's immutable and cached on first access.
2. The Dart compilation environment available through
   `String.fromEnvironment`. That environment is set at compile-time and
   cannot be changed.

```
/// Code Example:
///
/// dart --define=BASE_URL=https://google.com run bin/main.dart 'ONLY TEST' 'ONLY TEST TWO'
///
void main(List<String> args) {
  print(String.fromEnvironment('BASE_URL')); // https://google.com

  print(args[0]); // ONLY TEST

  print(args[1]); // ONLY TEST TWO
}
```